# PHP не грузятся данные из БД

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Создаю функцию редактирования. После нажатия "Редактировать" должна открыться форма с предыдущими значениями, так что пользователь может исправить необходимые данные. Добавила форму, но данные из БД не грузятся почему-то. Выходят названия (Программа, код, курс и т.д.) и пустые текстовые области.
Код:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("university") or die(mysql_error());
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}'");
$news=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
    <label>Название
        <input name="program" type="text" id="program" value=<?php echo $news[‘program’]; ?>/>
        <br />Код:
        <input name="code" type="text" id="code" value=<?php echo $news[‘price’]; ?>/> Курс:
        <input name="course" type="text" id="course" value=<?php echo $news[‘course’]; ?>/> Форма:
        <input name="form" type="text" id="form" value=<?php echo $news[‘form’]; ?>/> Срок:
        <input name="time" type="text" id="time" value=<?php echo $news[‘time’]; ?>/> Цена:
        <input name="price" type="text" id="price" value=<?php echo $news[‘price’]; ?>/> Акредитация:
        <input name="accreditation" type="text" id="accreditation" value=<?php echo $news[‘accreditation’]; ?>/> Кафедра:
        <input name="department" type="text" id="department" value=<?php echo $news[‘department’]; ?>/> Уровень:
        <input name="level" type="text" id="level" value=<?php echo $news[‘level’]; ?>/> Тип:
        <input name="type" type="text" id="type" value=<?php echo $news[‘type’]; ?>/>
    </label>
    <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value=”<?php echo $news[‘id’] ?>”/>
    <input name="progra," type="hidden" id="program" />
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="сохранить" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь одинарные кавычки лишние (как в самом запросе, так и при указании ключа массива):

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}'");
```

=>

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '.(int)$_GET['id'];
$res = mysql_query($query);
```